# How to find all occurences of a substring in a numpy string array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I'm trying to find all occurences of a substring in a numpy string array. Let's say:

```
myArray = np.array(['Time', 'utc_sec', 'UTC_day', 'Utc_Hour'])
sub = 'utc'
```

It should be case insensitive, so the method should return [1,2,3].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *vectorized* approach using [`np.char.lower`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.lower.html) and [`np.char.find`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.char.find.html)

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array(['Time', 'utc_sec', 'UTC_day', 'Utc_Hour'])
res = np.where(np.char.find(np.char.lower(myArray), 'utc') > -1)[0]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 3]
```

The idea is to use `np.char.lower` to make `np.char.find` *case-insensitive*, then fetch the indices that contains the sub-string using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if sub in string` to check it.

```py
import numpy as np

myArray = np.array(['Time', 'utc_sec', 'UTC_day', 'Utc_Hour'])
sub = 'utc'

count = 0
found = []
for item in myArray:
    if sub in item.lower():
        count += 1
        found.append(count)

print(found)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use list `comprehension` te get the right indexes :

```
occ = [i for i in range(len(myArray)) if 'utc' in myArray[i].lower()]
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(occ)
... [1, 2, 3]
```

Let's make a general use from this question: we will set up a function returning occurences indexes of `any` sub-character inside a `numpy string array`.

```
get_occ_idx(sub, np_array):
    """ Occurences index of substring in a numpy string array
    """
    
    assert sub.islower(), f"Your substring '{sub}' must be lower case (should be : {sub.lower()})"
    assert all(isinstance(x, str)==False for x in np_array), "All items in the array must be strings"
    assert all(sub in x.lower() for x in np_array), f"There is no occurence of substring :'{sub}'"
    
    occ = [i for i in range(len(np_array)) if sub in np_array[i].lower()]
    
    return occ
```